# Is it possible to customize the Finder status bar?

Tags: finder, statusbar

By default the status bar will display the number of elements in the current folder and the available disk space.

I remember having the current selected file name displayed instead of those informations, but my laptop has been freshly reinstalled since and I can't remember how I configured this status bar back then.

Is it possible to configure what's displayed in the Finder status bar?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you're confusing the Status Bar with the Path Bar.
You can have either/or - one shows file count & remaining disk space, the other the path to the selected file.

[image]

Oddly, but it's been this way for a long time, if you hide the Toolbar, the Status Bar jumps to the top of the window instead of the bottom… & the Sidebar becomes unavailable.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what I had done then, but I remember having the full file name displayed in place of what is the default status bar. Only when selecting a file of course.

Comment: They've always been in separate 'boxes'. This pic from Snow Leopard, 10.6.8 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl6tk.png

Comment: By full name I don't mean full path, what I used to see somewhere was the full file name (which are almost always truncated with ellipsis if not in list view). This info is no where in Finder by default, even tooltip will not show the full file name.

Comment: The path shows the full name, if there's room, otherwise it fades it out to the right rather than truncate it. It will truncate all the rest of the hierarchy first, to try keep the name visible.

Comment: Oh right, I thougt it only showed the directories and not the file, my bad. Still not what I remember having but it does the trick to see the full file name. Thx!